# In Tears of the Kingdom is there a workaround for using an Amiibo more than once per day?

Tags: amiibo, zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom

Each unique amiibo unlock random loot, but can only be used once every 24 hours in The Legend of Zelda: Tears of the Kingdom. If you try and exceed the limit you will receive the message “This amiibo can’t be used again today.”

Is there a way to use a given Amiibo more than once in a 24 hour period?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to exceed the amiibo daily usage restriction in Zelda: Tears of the Kingdom and utilize them multiple times in a day.

To accomplish this, you must save and quit the game, and then adjust the date on your Switch to the following day.

To set your Switch time forward:

1. On the Switch Main Menu, go to System Settings.
2. Scroll down to System.
3. Select Date and Time.
4. Turn off *Synchronize Clock via Internet.*
5. Highlight Date and Time and then manually set the day forward.
6. Relaunch your game and reuse the amiibo

Rinse and repeat until collect all desired items from the given amiibo. After you are done be sure to set your Switch back to *Synchronize Clock via Internet* as having an incorrect date and time set can prevent you from using the eShop.